# How I would be able to change bubbles color if checkbox is checked?

Tags: jquery

I have this code below. I'm wondering, how I would be able to change bubbles color to white, if checkbox is checked. I can easily change background color with CSS, but I'm not sure how I could change it in jQuery script. At the moment bubbles color is defined at the end of jQuery code. This jQuery code confusing me a lot.

```js
window.lavaAnimation = (function () {
  "use strict";
  var t,
    i = {
      screen: {
        elem: null,
        callback: null,
        ctx: null,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        init: function (t, i, s) {
          return (
            (this.elem = document.getElementById(t)),
            (this.callback = i || null),
            "CANVAS" == this.elem.tagName &&
              (this.ctx = this.elem.getContext("2d")),
            window.addEventListener(
              "resize",
              function () {
                this.resize();
              }.bind(this),
              !1
            ),
            (this.elem.onselectstart = function () {
              return !1;
            }),
            (this.elem.ondrag = function () {
              return !1;
            }),
            s && this.resize(),
            this
          );
        },
        resize: function () {
          var t = this.elem;
          for (
            this.width = t.offsetWidth,
              this.height = t.offsetHeight,
              this.left = 0,
              this.top = 0;
            null != t;
            t = t.offsetParent
          )
            (this.left += t.offsetLeft), (this.top += t.offsetTop);
          this.ctx &&
            ((this.elem.width = this.width), (this.elem.height = this.height)),
            this.callback && this.callback();
        }
      }
    },
    s = function (t, i) {
      (this.x = t),
        (this.y = i),
        (this.magnitude = t * t + i * i),
        (this.computed = 0),
        (this.force = 0);
    };
  s.prototype.add = function (t) {
    return new s(this.x + t.x, this.y + t.y);
  };
  var h = function (t) {
    var i = 0.1,
      h = 1.5;
    (this.vel = new s(
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + 0.25 * Math.random()),
      (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * (0.2 + Math.random())
    )),
      (this.pos = new s(
        0.2 * t.width + Math.random() * t.width * 0.6,
        0.2 * t.height + Math.random() * t.height * 0.6
      )),
      (this.size = t.wh / 15 + (Math.random() * (h - i) + i) * (t.wh / 15)),
      (this.width = t.width),
      (this.height = t.height);
  };
  h.prototype.move = function () {
    this.pos.x >= this.width - this.size
      ? (this.vel.x > 0 && (this.vel.x = -this.vel.x),
        (this.pos.x = this.width - this.size))
      : this.pos.x <= this.size &&
        (this.vel.x < 0 && (this.vel.x = -this.vel.x),
        (this.pos.x = this.size)),
      this.pos.y >= this.height - this.size
        ? (this.vel.y > 0 && (this.vel.y = -this.vel.y),
          (this.pos.y = this.height - this.size))
        : this.pos.y <= this.size &&
          (this.vel.y < 0 && (this.vel.y = -this.vel.y),
          (this.pos.y = this.size)),
      (this.pos = this.pos.add(this.vel));
  };
  var e = function (t, i, e, n, a) {
    (this.step = 5),
      (this.width = t),
      (this.height = i),
      (this.wh = Math.min(t, i)),
      (this.sx = Math.floor(this.width / this.step)),
      (this.sy = Math.floor(this.height / this.step)),
      (this.paint = !1),
      (this.metaFill = r(t, i, t, n, a)),
      (this.plx = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
      (this.ply = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]),
      (this.mscases = [0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0]),
      (this.ix = [
        1,
        0,
        -1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        -1,
        -1,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        1
      ]),
      (this.grid = []),
      (this.balls = []),
      (this.iter = 0),
      (this.sign = 1);
    for (var o = 0; o < (this.sx + 2) * (this.sy + 2); o++)
      this.grid[o] = new s(
        (o % (this.sx + 2)) * this.step,
        Math.floor(o / (this.sx + 2)) * this.step
      );
    for (var l = 0; e > l; l++) this.balls[l] = new h(this);
  };
  (e.prototype.computeForce = function (t, i, s) {
    var h,
      e = s || t + i * (this.sx + 2);
    if (0 === t || 0 === i || t === this.sx || i === this.sy)
      h = 0.6 * this.sign;
    else {
      h = 0;
      for (var r, n = this.grid[e], a = 0; (r = this.balls[a++]); )
        h +=
          (r.size * r.size) /
          (-2 * n.x * r.pos.x -
            2 * n.y * r.pos.y +
            r.pos.magnitude +
            n.magnitude);
      h *= this.sign;
    }
    return (this.grid[e].force = h), h;
  }),
    (e.prototype.marchingSquares = function (t) {
      var i = t[0],
        s = t[1],
        h = t[2],
        e = i + s * (this.sx + 2);
      if (this.grid[e].computed === this.iter) return !1;
      for (var r, n = 0, a = 0; 4 > a; a++) {
        var l = i + this.ix[a + 12] + (s + this.ix[a + 16]) * (this.sx + 2),
          d = this.grid[l].force;
        ((d > 0 && this.sign < 0) || (0 > d && this.sign > 0) || !d) &&
          (d = this.computeForce(i + this.ix[a + 12], s + this.ix[a + 16], l)),
          Math.abs(d) > 1 && (n += Math.pow(2, a));
      }
      if (15 === n) return [i, s - 1, !1];
      5 === n
        ? (r = 2 === h ? 3 : 1)
        : 10 === n
        ? (r = 3 === h ? 0 : 2)
        : ((r = this.mscases[n]), (this.grid[e].computed = this.iter));
      var p =
        this.step /
        (Math.abs(
          Math.abs(
            this.grid[
              i +
                this.plx[4 * r + 2] +
                (s + this.ply[4 * r + 2]) * (this.sx + 2)
            ].force
          ) - 1
        ) /
          Math.abs(
            Math.abs(
              this.grid[
                i +
                  this.plx[4 * r + 3] +
                  (s + this.ply[4 * r + 3]) * (this.sx + 2)
              ].force
            ) - 1
          ) +
          1);
      return (
        o.lineTo(
          this.grid[i + this.plx[4 * r] + (s + this.ply[4 * r]) * (this.sx + 2)]
            .x +
            this.ix[r] * p,
          this.grid[
            i + this.plx[4 * r + 1] + (s + this.ply[4 * r + 1]) * (this.sx + 2)
          ].y +
            this.ix[r + 4] * p
        ),
        (this.paint = !0),
        [i + this.ix[r + 4], s + this.ix[r + 8], r]
      );
    }),
    (e.prototype.renderMetaballs = function () {
      for (var t, i = 0; (t = this.balls[i++]); ) t.move();
      for (
        this.iter++,
          this.sign = -this.sign,
          this.paint = !1,
          o.fillStyle = this.metaFill,
          o.beginPath(),
          i = 0;
        (t = this.balls[i++]);

      ) {
        var s = [
          Math.round(t.pos.x / this.step),
          Math.round(t.pos.y / this.step),
          !1
        ];
        do s = this.marchingSquares(s);
        while (s);
        this.paint &&
          (o.fill(), o.closePath(), o.beginPath(), (this.paint = !1));
      }
    });
  var r = function (t, i, s, h, e) {
    var r = o.createRadialGradient(t / 1, i / 1, 0, t / 1, i / 1, s);
    return r.addColorStop(0, h), r.addColorStop(1, e), r;
  };
  if (document.getElementById("lamp-anim")) {
    var n = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(n),
          o.clearRect(0, 0, a.width, a.height),
          t.renderMetaballs();
      },
      a = i.screen.init("lamp-anim", null, !0),
      o = a.ctx;
    a.resize(),
      (t = new e(
        a.width,
        a.height,
        6,
        "rgb(149, 56, 122, 0.5)",
        "rgb(223, 1, 128, 0.5)"
      ));
  }
  return { run: n };
})();

if (document.getElementById("lamp-anim")) {
  lavaAnimation.run();
}
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".js-works-d-list").addClass("is-loaded");
}, 150);
```

```css
.swiper-slide {
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

canvas {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
#lightmode {
  display: none;
}
#lightmode + label {
  position: fixed;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#lightmode + label:before {
  border-radius: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    content: "Light";
    text-align: center;
    background: #333;
    transition: background 200ms ease;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10PX;
}

#lightmode:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  color: #fff;
  content: "Light";
  font-weight: bold;
}

#lightmode:checked ~ .swiper-slide  {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #95387a,#df0180);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="lightmode">
    <label for="lightmode"></label>
<div class="swiper-slide ">
    <canvas id="lamp-anim" class="lamp-anim"></canvas>
</div>
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: `e()` seems to be your constructor that adds properties for dimension and color, find the name of the color properties(which seem to be inherited from `r`), find what your bubbles are bound to and then fill on 'lightmode' checked (`$('#lightmode').on('checked', ()=>bubbles.fill = rgb(0,0,0))`).. Unfortunately the code is very badly eligable to say for sure without fiddling around with it for an hour. My tip for you is to strip down as many elements as possible to see what does what.

Comment: This query code is horrible. Changing the color of an element by query is pretty easy and you only need three lines of code. I don't know what all this stuff in your code should be good for

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff I didn't write this jQuery code, I used this example from Code Pen https://codepen.io/innersociety/pen/rEXoer